# html input field restrictions

Tags: javascript, html

My input field restrictions are not working. The form submits and logs the data no matter the restrictions. How can I fix this? for context I am working in next.js in a .jsx file.

```js
if (!Boolean(userToken))
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p className="">address: {address}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        id="form"
        className="absolute p-10 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 border-2 rounded-md shadow-lg top-1/3 left-1/2 "
      >
        <h2 className="flex p-5 text-2xl font-semibold"> Link Username </h2>
        <form id="" className="">
          <input
            id="username"
            className="m-5 border-2 rounded outline-0 focus:bg-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-50"
            type="text"
            value={userName}
            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
            required
            minLength="3"
            maxLength="30"
            pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
            title="only letters, numbers, and underscores."
          />
          <button
            className="p-1 rounded hover:bg-slate-100 actve:bg-slate-200"
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e) => writeUserData(address, userName)}
          >
            Link Name
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Your code snippet shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you put `onClick` event on the button. It will trigger no matter what your restriction is.

I'd suggest that you should put `onSubmit` on `form` instead. That will help you to do the validations first. If all validations are passed, the form submission event will be triggered properly.

*One site note, all your restrictions are applied on form submission except `maxLength`, which is applied directly on the input field.*

```js
const { useState } = React
const App = () => {
   const [userName, setUsername] = useState()
   return <form onSubmit={() => console.log('Submitted successfully')}>
   <input
            id="username"
            className="m-5 border-2 rounded outline-0 focus:bg-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-50"
            type="text"
            value={userName}
            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
            required
            minLength="3"
            maxLength="30"
            pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
            title="only letters, numbers, and underscores."
          />
          <button
        className="p-1 rounded hover:bg-slate-100 actve:bg-slate-200"
        type="submit"
      >
        Link Name
      </button>
   </form>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```